# Volume between two cylinders and planes

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Get the volume between $z=x^2$, $y=x^2$, $z=0$ and $y=4$. I have to compute it using double integrals.

I'm not sure if should I set up two double integrals, or how to even get the needed region.

At the moment, I know that if $z=0$ then $x=0$, and if $y=4$ then $x=2$ or $x=-2$.

I also thought about $f(x,y)=2x^2-y$ to mix those two parabolic cylinders, but I can't see it geometrically.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure but how do you use double integrals to get volume..?

Comment: Integrantes type I, II or III regions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region is shown in the image:
[image]
(The plane $y=4$ is not shown). Its volume can be calculated as
$\iint_{S} z(x,y)\,dx\,dy$, where $z(x,y)=x^2$ and $S$ is

[image]

The value of the volume is
$$
\iint_{S} x^2\,dx\,dy=\int_{-2}^{2}\,dx \int_{x^2}^4 x^2\, dy=
\int_{-2}^{2}x^2y\Big|_{x^2}^4 \,dx=
\int_{-2}^{2} x^2(4-x^2)\, dx=\frac{128}{15}.
$$

Comment: I just understood the whole problem, thank you!